# Where is Java JDK on Macintosh El Capitan?

Tags: java, macos, path

I know there are a lots of question like this but they seem to reefer to an old version of java or an old os environment, so i am forced to make the question again: how can i find the path of java jdk on my mac? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Try following command in your Macintosh terminal window

```
> echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

it will show the location of installed JDK.

**Output**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: it returns this   -bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home: is a directory    but when i go into my library there is no "Java" folder and i am sure to have it install because i see in my settings panel

Comment: This is the location of your installed JDK. Change directory into `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/‌​Home` and see its contents.

Comment: @TechInspector My strongest suspicion is that your Macintosh is hiding the user's Library directory? There is command to show: `chflags nohidden ~/Library/`

Comment: Library is not hidden because i access it easily

Answer (score 1):

there is a command $java -verbose. It returns complete path at the end of command.[image]